# Can i sort query set return objects in order to function result

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am writing a web based music application and I want implement some feature that user can see most favor album in last week-month-year.
so this is my model :

```
class album(models.Model):
   def get_weely_count():
      ...
   def get_monthly_count():
      ...

   def get_yearly_count():
      ...

class like(models.Model):
   created_at = models.DateField()
   albumID = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

Now I want to receive albums that most liked in last week or last month or last year,I want done some thing like this(but I can not):

```
Album.objects.all().order_by('get_weekly_count')
```

can any one help me to fix it or give another approach to achieve that goal??

Comment: what is your current result? and what is expected?

Comment: `order_by` is applied at database level that's why you can't use it with a regular python function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `order_by` method translates into an SQL `ORDER BY`, therefore it works only with model fields, which correspond to table columns. It won't work if you intend to sort your elements by a model's method.
So, if you want to accomplish something like

```
Album.objects.all().order_by('get_weekly_count')
```

You'll have to do it the python way

```
sorted(Album.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.get_weekly_count())
```

Performance-wise, this means you'll get your elements with a query and then you'll sort them with python (that's different from getting a sorted queryset in one shot).
Otherwise, if it's possible for you to turn `get_weekly_count` into raw SQL, you could use it with a `Count()` or an `extra` modifier, that would make `order_by` usable, i.e.:

```
Album.objects.all().extra(
    select={'weekly_count': "<some SQL>"},
    select_params=(<you params>,),
).order_by('weekly_count')
```

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, you should use:

```
from django.db.models import Count
like.objects.filter(created_at__gt=START_OF_MONTH, created_at__lt=Datetime.now()).values('albumID').annotate(count=Count('albumID')).order_by('count')
```

This will get results for you in **single db query**. For more details visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/.