# filtering objects in descending order in django

Tags: python, html, django, object

I am trying to show a table of schools in a cluster(city or town) in a descending order with respect to school average marks.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>Strength</th>
        <th>Average</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for school in school_order %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'data:school_detail' state.id region.id cluster.id school.id %}">{{ school.school_name }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ school.strength }}</td>
            <td>{{ school.get_average }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the table I'm trying to display in my template

```
school_order = cluster.school_set.all().order_by('-get_average')
```

This is how I'm trying to get school_order in view.py

get_average is not a field for model school but it is a method I used in the model.

```
class School(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = ChainedForeignKey(Region, chained_field="state",chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cluster = ChainedForeignKey(Cluster, chained_field="region",chained_model_field="region", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    facilitator = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    f_number = models.IntegerField()
    f_email = models.EmailField()
    school_logo = models.FileField(default='')
    strength = models.IntegerField()

    def get_average(self):
        return self.avergae_set.latest('average_date').average_value
```

This is my model for school.

The error I'm getting is cannot resolve keyword 'get_average' into field.

Please help!

Comment: You can't pass a method to `order_by`. You can, however, use Python's built-in `sorted()` function to sort a queryset using a method as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32050078/1925257). Also, you've a spelling mistake at `avergae_set`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Django ORM's orderby for non model field. You can convert the queryset to list and do sort in python.

```
school_order = list(cluster.school_set.all())
                    .sort(key=lambda x: x.get_average, reverse=True)
```

Other options are you can you select extra or annotate.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#annotate